# Set bookable product base cost programatically in Woocommerce Bookings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-bookings

I am trying to calculate the Base cost of a WooCommerce bookable product and managed to get it done using this:

```
    function modify_baseprice() {
       global $post;
       $productid = $post->ID;
       $product = new WC_Product($productid);
       $product_block_price = $product->wc_booking_block_cost;
       $product->wc_booking_cost = ($product_block_price*0.6) + 100;
       $pricing_data = update_post_meta( $productid, '_wc_booking_cost', $product->wc_booking_cost); 
       return $pricing_data; 
   }
   add_action( 'woocommerce_bookings_after_booking_base_cost', 'modify_baseprice', 10, 3 );
```

It does calculate the Base cost correctly but I need to refresh the page twice to see it appearing on the Base cost field. Is there a way that I can get it to appear after the first save?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Woocommerce 3 release, [CRUD objects](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) have been implemented. It's the case of `WC_Product` object and also for Woocommerce Bookings plugin. So you can use available Getters and setters methods as properties are not anymore accessible (in most cases).

The following code use this better way *(The cost is set in the product without any need of refreshing the page)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_booking', 'modify_bookable_product_base_cost', 100, 1 );
function modify_bookable_product_base_cost( $product_id ){
    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    // We check that we have a block cost before
    if ( $product->get_block_cost() > 0 ){
        // Calculation
        $new_booking_cost = ( $product->get_block_cost() * 0.6 ) + 100;

        $product->set_cost( $new_booking_cost ); // Set the new calculated cost in the product
        $product->save(); // Save the product data
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Could you kindly explain if we can use something similar to control the other items on Add new product screen? For example I want to make the Bookable item as the default if not the only item for some user roles and hide/remove all non essential options. Since the introduction of CRUD objects certain filters 'default_product_type' for example, no longer working.